# Selecting p-highest values of a dataframe with their according positions

Tags: r, dplyr

Good afternoon !

Assume we have the following dataframe :

```
M1=structure(c(NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 0.0189718128018973, 
0.294303552937154, NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.0189718128018973, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.294303552937154, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.047284597249565, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.10826822658929, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.0189718128018973, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0690701037282896, NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0290200490396767, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0217379689377885, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.033863375698564, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.0189718128018973, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, NA), .Dim = c(24L, 24L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24")))
```

I'm searching to extract their p-maximum values with their associated positions , i had already found :

```
nlargest <- function(m, n){
  
  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(as.vector(m), expand.grid(1:nrow(m), 1:ncol(m))))
  colnames(df) <- c("value", "row", "column")
  
  largest <- dplyr::distinct(df, value, .keep_all = T) %>% 
    dplyr::slice_max(order_by = value, n = n)

 

  l <- list(values = largest$value,
            position = largest[, c("row", "column")])
  
  return(l)
}
```

Output :

```
N_highest=10

res=nlargest(M1, N_highest)

res$value

[1] 0.29430355 0.19449339 0.14153697 0.10826823 0.08550234 0.06907010
 [7] 0.04728460 0.03982965 0.03386338 0.02902005
```

The desired output is :

```
 res$value
 [1] 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036
 [8] 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036
```

However , **i'm not willing to select only the **p largest distinct values**** so i'm trying to change :

```
  largest <- dplyr::distinct(df, value, .keep_all = T) %>% 
    dplyr::slice_max(order_by = value, n = n)
```

with :

```
  largest <- dplyr::slice_max(df , order_by = value, n = n)
```

This doesn't work as expected. I hope my question is clear.

Thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: actually output of `slice_max()` is a list and that may be the problem.  However, please clarify what is your desired output

Comment: @AnilGoyal  , i updated the post. The code should do the same as the function `nlargest()` but without considering the p-highest distinct entries of the matrix ``M1`

Comment: Question could be closed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this will also help

```
nlargest <- function(m, n){
  
  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(as.vector(m), expand.grid(1:nrow(m), 1:ncol(m))))
  colnames(df) <- c("value", "row", "column")
  
  largest <- dplyr::arrange(df, value) %>%
    dplyr::slice_max(dense_rank(value), n = n) %>% filter(row_number() <= n)
  
  
  
  l <- list(values = largest$value,
            position = largest[, c("row", "column")])
  
  return(l)
}
```

check it

```
N_highest=10

res=nlargest(M1,N_highest)

res$value

> res$value
 [1] 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036
```

Comment: i will use your solution because it simplify for me my main code modification ! Thank you a lot for your valuable help !

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution :

```
library(dplyr)
M1=structure(c(NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 0.0189718128018973, 
0.294303552937154, NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.0189718128018973, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.294303552937154, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.047284597249565, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.10826822658929, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.0189718128018973, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0690701037282896, NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0290200490396767, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.194493387547371, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.294303552937154, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0217379689377885, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.033863375698564, 0.047284597249565, 0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.10826822658929, 0.294303552937154, NA, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.033863375698564, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.0189718128018973, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0398296546942912, 0.10826822658929, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 0.194493387547371, 0.141536965054211, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, NA, 
0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0290200490396767, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 0.033863375698564, 
0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 
0.10826822658929, 0.0855023405283086, 0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 
0.141536965054211, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 
0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
NA, 0.294303552937154, 0.0189718128018973, 0.0290200490396767, 
0.033863375698564, 0.0217379689377885, 0.033863375698564, 0.0398296546942912, 
0.0398296546942912, 0.0690701037282896, 0.0855023405283086, 0.047284597249565, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.10826822658929, 0.0690701037282896, 0.141536965054211, 
0.194493387547371, 0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 
0.0855023405283086, 0.194493387547371, 0.294303552937154, 0.10826822658929, 
0.294303552937154, NA), .Dim = c(24L, 24L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
    "22", "23", "24"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
    "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24")))

  df <- as.data.frame(cbind(as.vector(M1), expand.grid(1:nrow(M1), 1:ncol(M1))))
  colnames(df) <- c("value", "row", "column")
  
  n=10
  largest <- df %>% group_by(desc(value)) %>% slice_head(n = n)
  largest <-largest[1:n,]

  l <- list(values = largest$value,
            position = largest[, c("row", "column")])

  l
```

Output :

```
$values
 [1] 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036
 [8] 0.2943036 0.2943036 0.2943036

$position
# A tibble: 10 x 2
     row column
   <int>  <int>
 1     2      1
 2     4      1
 3     7      1
 4     1      2
 5     3      2
 6     5      2
 7     8      2
 8     2      3
 9     6      3
10     9      3
```